# How do I recover Laravel Valet after attempting to change the TLD from .test to .dev?

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet, valet

I successfully installed valet and had it working. I was able to verify this by successfully accessing my first linked domain testdomain.test.

I'm working on my project with another developer. I wanted to change my setup to match his entirely so when we were discussing things or having issues, everything matched letter to letter.

I ran `valet tld dev` andf got the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/Users/myuser/.config/valet/Nginx/testdomain.test.dev): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/myuser/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/Valet/Filesystem.php on line 112

Warning: file_get_contents(/Users/myuser/.config/valet/Nginx/testdomain.test.dev): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/bryansalva/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/Valet/Filesystem.php on line 112
```

Now neither TLD works. I've tried:

- Unlinking and relinking
- Changing back to .test
- Uninstalling Valet config then reinstalling and relinking
- Uninstalling Valet entirely, upgrading composer, and starting from scratch.
- Updating PHP

I'ver tried every post I've been able to find on the subject and nothing seems to be working. It worked before my first TLD change. It hasn't worked since. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/695) post?

Comment: I have seen it, yes. It comes up when googling the error message we're receiving. That said, the link you shared is a PHP permissions error. The error I'm getting seems to be related to Valet looking for "testdomain.test.dev" instead of what is actually in that folder "testdomain.test" or testdomain.dev" depending on which TLD I'm using. A fresh install seemes to have issues too, though. So, I'm pretty lost.